# How to read most recent line from stdin in python

Tags: python, stdin

Is there way to read only the current data from stdin?

I would like to pipe some never-ending input data (from a mouse like device) into a python script and grab only the most recent line of data.

The input x,y data looks like this and arrives at 600 lines per second:

```
0.123,0.123
0.244,0.566
etc.
```

So far I have tried something like this:

```
import sys, time

while 1:
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
    my_slow_function(data)
```

Python seems to buffer the data so nothing is skipped. I would like to skip everything except the current line.

Comment: How do you know when it is the line?

Comment: I am looking for only the latest line data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just spin up a separate thread to read stdin into a global variable. Make it a daemon thread so that you don't have to close it later on. The thread reads the data as it arrives and keeps discarding the old stuff. Have your regular program read last_line when it wants to.

I added an event so that the regular program can wait when no new data is available. If that's not what you want, take it out.

```
import sys
import threading

last_line = ''
new_line_event = threading.Event()


def keep_last_line():
    global last_line, new_line_event
    for line in sys.stdin:
        last_line = line
        new_line_event.set()

keep_last_line_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_last_line)
keep_last_line_thread.daemon = True
keep_last_line_thread.start()
```

Comment: This is the right answer. [Portable, non-blocking stdin reads are not straightforward without threading.](http://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/) You probably want to remove the `()` from `global new_line_event()`, though; I'm pretty sure Events aren't callable.

Comment: This works! As @Henry points out the () on the end of new_line_event does not work. Also, sys.stdin does not require brackets. Thanks!

Comment: @HenryKeiter - oops, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the current line, only act on the last line.

```
buffer = None
for line in sys.stdin:
    buffer = line
my_slow_function(buffer)
```

Comment: I would not call this a hack :)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work because stdin is constant. It comes from a device. So the for loop never ends.

Comment: @chriskelly so there is no such thing as a last line.

Comment: @chriskelly, is that an input device such as a keyboard? If so, hit `[Ctrl+D]` (or `[Ctrl+Z], [Enter]` on Windows) to have it send `EOF` to your program.

Comment: @chriskelly What is "the last line" for you?

Comment: Sorry if I am explaining it wrong. I just need to know the current position of a mouse-like device.